# getting this error *** Android NDK: Aborting... .Stop

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

i am trying to work with Open CV in Eclipse for Android Juno.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. Downloaded NDK version r10b
2. Went to `WINDOW -> PREFRENCES -> ANDROID -> NDK` and gave the path of my NDK
3. Went to OpenCV library project properties in C++ build set the environment variable NDKROOT and the path is the same as in step 3.
4. In C++ build changed the build command from `make` to `${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd`

Now the problem is I am getting this error:

```
 ***ANDROID NDK: ABORTING... .Stop .
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need  set the path from the NDK  or compile with c++ build. ..

You only need  include the opencvlibrary_2.4.9.jar  in your project.

and include folder armeabi-v7a  in your libs to some dispositives. .

Comment: what jar file i cant find it in my project

Comment: http://opencv.org/downloads.html  ... Download OpenCv. export project.   Folder bin/opencvlibrary_2.4.9.jar .